# Failed due to illegal value in property: context

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have a google apps script using jquery,jquery-ui and jquery-mobile. The html is a simple form with a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm($('#form'))" />
```

When I load as web app and click on the button I get:

```
3359132324-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: context
```

The code is obfuscated and I can't make sense out of it. I tried to use Logger.log in processForm, nothing appears in View -> Logs. Execution transcript is:

```
[14-12-25 17:06:15:613 IST] Starting execution
[14-12-25 17:06:15:649 IST] Execution succeeded [0.0 seconds total runtime]
```

If I set a breakpoint, the script doesn't stop there (I guess this is because it is deployed as a web app, can I change that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `processForm()` method is expecting a native `HTMLElement` argument, not a jQuery context.

Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
  onclick="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
      .processForm($('#form').get(0))" />
```

See [jQuery get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: Yes, or simply `processForm($('#form')[0])`.